# Set and get values from multiple sliders

Tags: jquery, post, slider

The questions I have are regarding the following fiddle :

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Y5ZLL/4/
```

The fiddle actually takes 400 as the maximum value and the total of the four sliders does not exceed 400. There are two questions attached to the above fiddle:

1. How can I grab each jQuery slider value after form post.
2. How can I set different inital value to each slider as I will be using the same page to update values in the database as well?

Comment: I think this question needs more clarification? what form post? Would you please elaborate this form thing in a bit detail?

Comment: Form means if you see the fiddle you will see the code bearing ul and li that is creating the slider. If that html code is submitted using form and submit button, how can i grab the slider values. hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are using ajax, then you can, if you are using plane old form post, then you can not, you have to create a hidden field associated with every slider to take the value to the server side file.

Comment: So apart from the span that is displaying the value i have to create hidden field per slide to grab the post value, right? Also how can i set different initial value in the fiddle i sent in my initial post. Please let me know. I was truly hoping for some code help here...

Comment: You dont need code help, you are just doing fine, but the check this fiddle anyway, you will see very little has been modified

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZLL/1135/

I have just added text input box, instead of hidden fields to make the changes visible.

Comment: I am working on it right now. Just one last thing please . How can i set the inital value to each slider separately? This part is important as when i will use the same sliders to update the records i have to give them the value that was already input before. Please let me know.

Comment: Check the fiddle, you just have to put the initial/updated values in each associated text box with server side script, retrieve those values and change the option 'value' of the sliders accordingly.